# Comparison And Ordering in Go

Tags: comparison, operator-overloading, go, equality, comparable

Is there any internal mechanism in Go for implementing equality and ordering? (So we can use comparison operators on the type - ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=.)

Note: I saw some types have a method named Less which seems to be used for ordering. But I can not find the documentation for that or for equality checking interface (if there is any).

Comment: This is probably what you're talking about: [sort](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface). Doesn't do equality.

Comment: @tjameson: of course, if it's a total ordering, then less than is sufficient to define equality (and any other comparison): `a == b` is just `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go [does not support operator overloading](http://golang.org/doc/faq#overloading), so you won't be able to override the behaviour of those operators with your type.  If you need to use those operations on your type, then define them as methods.

The `Less` method you may have seen on some types is probably there as part of the [`sort.Interface`](http://godoc.org/sort#Interface) interface or possibly [`heap.Interface`](http://godoc.org/container/heap#Interface) (which extends the sort interface).

Comment: this is an example of awesome features of C++ and why I admire it.